# Unable to use builtin CA bundle to verify GoDaddy SHA2 SSL certificate

Tags: centos, php, ssl-certificate, openssl

I ran into an interesting problem. We have a PHP script that contacts a LTL shipper (https://facts.dohrn.com/). That script has been failing because it can't validate the SSL certificate. I went to the site and found they were using a GoDaddy SHA2 certificate (uses the [GoDaddy Certificate Bundles - G2](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository), which is what is used for SHA2).

I have the latest version of `ca-certificate` installed and it looks like they have **Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2** but that's not the same thing and fails in all forms of validation. I was able to finally get it to work by copying the bundle and directly using that in a CURL request. But this is simply a workaround. Is there something else I'm missing that could make this work without installing the CA directly?

> # openssl s_client -connect facts.dohrn.com:443 
>   CONNECTED(00000003) depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = facts.dohrn.com verify
>   error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:1
>   depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = facts.dohrn.com verify
>   error:num=27:certificate not trusted verify return:1 depth=0 OU =
>   Domain Control Validated, CN = facts.dohrn.com verify
>   error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate verify return:1
>   --- Certificate chain  0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=facts.dohrn.com   
>   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com,
>   Inc./OU=`http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN`=Go Daddy Secure
>   Certificate Authority - G2
>   --- Server certificate [certificate removed]
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
>   subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=facts.dohrn.com
>   issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com,
>   Inc./OU=`http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN`=Go Daddy Secure
>   Certificate Authority - G2
>   --- No client certificate CA names sent
>   --- SSL handshake has read 1470 bytes and written 563 bytes
>   --- New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported Compression: NONE Expansion:
>   NONE SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1
>       Cipher    : RC4-SHA
>       Session-ID: 1A23000017A7003411F3833970B7FA23C6D782E663CE0C8B17DE4D5A15DEE1A5
>       Session-ID-ctx:
>       Master-Key: F6C9C6345A09B7965AF762DE4BEFE8BDD249136BF30D9364598D78CF123F17230B0C25DD552F103BEF9A893F75EAD2B0
>       Key-Arg   : None
>       Krb5 Principal: None
>       PSK identity: None
>       PSK identity hint: None
>       Start Time: 1432044402
>       Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

Comment: What version of `ca-certificates` do you have installed? Post the output of `rpm -q ca-certificates`.

Comment: `ca-certificates-2015.2.4-65.0.1.el6_6.noarch` and yum shows no updates

Comment: Any ideas on what it could be then? I tried this on two other EL6 boxes, an EL5 and an EL7 box. All failed to validate the SSL.

Comment: Oops, no, I misread the output. It isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the web server at https://facts.dohrn.com/ does not include the intermediate certificate.

This would appear to be a configuration mistake on their part. It is definitely something that can be expected to cause compatibility issues as you are really only supposed to rely on clients having the root certificates in place beforehand.

See the certificate chain, eg from the [SSLLabs result](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=facts.dohrn.com): (You'll also note that there are many other issues with their SSL setup.)

```
1   Sent by server  facts.dohrn.com 
Fingerprint: 823e3a70f194c646498b2591069b3727ad0014d9 
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA

2   Extra download  Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2 
Fingerprint: 27ac9369faf25207bb2627cefaccbe4ef9c319b8 
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA

3   In trust store  Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2   Self-signed  
Fingerprint: 47beabc922eae80e78783462a79f45c254fde68b 
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
```

I would say that your main options are to either try to convince the service provider to fix their service or work around the problem on your end by providing the client with the certificates that their server was expected to provide.

Comment: Bingo, that was it. ... And since they're apparently running IIS 6 on 2003, they're well beyond the point where they should have done something about this.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense out of it. I'm not sure I'll be able to convince them to change anything but it's useful to have a diagnosis now.

Comment: I'm pleased to report they actually did fix a number of issues and brought their grade up to a C. It no longer throws the CA error.